# How to run test methods individually with Citrus Framework?

Tags: citrus-framework

I have the next code

```
@Test
public class ApiTestIT extends TestNGCitrusTestDesigner {
    @CitrusTest(name = "testApi2IT")
    public void testApi1IT() {
        //TO-DO here
    }

    @CitrusTest(name = "testApi2IT")
    public void testApi2IT() {
        echo("Hello Citrus!");
    }
}
```

How can i run test methods individually?

I trying using -Dtest and -Dit.test bad no work; always run the test at same time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute single test methods, you have to specify them in the `-Dit.test` specification like `-Dit.test=ApiTestIT#testApi2IT`.

Nevertheless, this functionality is not provided by citrus but by the maven failsafe plugin. For more information, have a look at the documentation for [Running a Single Test](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/single-test.html)

Some examples with citrus can be found in the [Citrus samples](https://github.com/citrusframework/citrus-samples) repository.